# AppleScript: Trying to write to a file when a POSIX path is provided

Tags: applescript

I am AppleScript nub and I am moments away from buying a type writer and moving into the mountains.

Can anyone, please, explain to me why this fails:

```
set mah_file to POSIX file "/Users/me/folder/fileinfo.txt"
set mah_data to "some text!!!!!!"

on write_to_file(this_data, target_file, append_data) -- (string, file path as string, boolean)
    try
        set the target_file to the target_file as text
        set the open_target_file to ¬
            open for access file of target_file with write permission
        if append_data is false then ¬
            set eof of the open_target_file to 0
        write this_data to the open_target_file starting at eof
        close access the open_target_file
        return true
    on error
        try
            close access file target_file
        end try
        return false
    end try
end write_to_file

write_to_file(mah_data, mah_file, true)
```

Even though this succeeds:

```
set mah_file to choose file
set mah_data to "some text!!!"

-- the rest is identical
```

I've tried:

```
set mah_file to POSIX file "/Users/me/folder/fileinfo.txt" as file
```

and

```
set mah_file to POSIX file "/Users/me/folder/fileinfo.txt" as alias
```

and

```
set mah_file to POSIX file "/Users/me/folder/fileinfo.txt" as text
```

And since AppleScript can't be bothered to tell me *why* this isn't working, I am well and truly losing my mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Leave out the `file` and `POSIX file` keywords:

```
set mah_file to "/Users/me/folder/fileinfo.txt"
...
set the open_target_file to open for access mah_file with write permission
```

Comment: Oh god is this a facepalm moment. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

`read` and `write` also use the primary encoding (like MacRoman or MacJapanese) by default. Add `as «class utf8»` to preserve non-ASCII characters in UTF-8 files.

Writing:

```
set b to open for access "/tmp/1" with write permission
set eof b to 0
write "α" to b as «class utf8»
close access b
```

Appending:

```
set b to open for access "/tmp/1" with write permission
write "ア" to b as «class utf8» starting at eof
close access b
```

Reading:

```
read "/usr/share/dict/connectives" as «class utf8»
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the echo command in combination with >> to write text to a file

if the textile doesn t exist a new one will be created

if the text file already exists and

you use > you can override an existing textile with the same name

you use >> the text will be added to the existing file

```
set mypath to "/Users/" & (short user name of (system info)) & "/Desktop/file.txt" as string
set myText to "text to write in the text file" as string

do shell script "echo " & "\"" & myText & "\"" & ">>" & mypath
```

and mypath is and POSIX path

hope that is what you was searching for